# Best Practice for Errors in RESTful API

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel, laravel-4

What are the best practices for returning HTTP status codes in RESTful API? I am using Laravel 4 for my PHP framework.

In the case of an error, should I use

```
return Response::json('User Exists', 401);
```

or

**include flag for `success`**

```
return Response::json([
    'success' => false,
    'data' => 'User Exists'],
    401
);
```

or

**use 200 instead of 4xx, relying on `success` to determine if there is an error**

```
return Response::json([
    'success' => false,
    'data' => 'User Exists'],
    200
);
```

And in the case of success and there is no need to return any data, do you still return anything?

**PHP API Code**

```
public function getCheckUniqueEmail() {
    // Check if Email already exist in table 'users'
    $uniqueEmail = checkIfEmailExists();

    // Return JSON Response
    if($uniqueEmail) {
        // Validation fail (user exists)
        return Response::json('User Exists', 401);
    } else {
        // Validation success
        // - Return anything?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you look at the [list of available HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), you will at some point realize that there are plenty of them, but used alone they cannot really explain an error by itself.

So to answer your question, there are two parts. One is: How can your API communicate the reasons for an error and add useful information that the user of the API (which in most cases is another developer) can read and act upon. You should add as much information as possible, both machine readable and human readable.

The other part: How can HTTP status codes help in distinguish certain error (and success) states?

This latter part is actually harder than one might thing. There are the obvious cases where 404 is used to tell "not found". And 500 for any errors that are server-side.

I wouldn't use status 401, unless I really want to allow the operation to succeed if there are HTTP authentication credentials present. 401 usually triggers a dialog box in the browser, which is bad.

In case of a ressource being unique and already existing, status "409 Conflict" seems appropriate. And if creating a user succeeds, status "201 Created" sounds like a good idea, too.

Note that there are a lot more status codes, some of them related to extensions of the HTTP protocol (like DAV), some completely unstandardized (like status "420 Enhance your calm" from the Twitter API). Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes to see what has been used so far, and decide whether you want to use something appropriate for your error cases.

From my experience, it is easy to simply pick a status code and use it, but it is hard to do so consistently and in accordance with existing standards.

I wouldn't however stop here just because others might complain. :) Doing RESTful interfaces right is a hard task in itself, but the more interfaces exists, the more experience has been gathered.

*Edit:*

Regarding versioning: It is considered bad practice to put a version tag into the URL, like so: `example.com/api/v1/stuff` It will work, but it isn't nice.

But the first thing is: How does your client specify which kind of representation he wants to get, i.e. how can he decide to either get JSON or XML? Answer: With the `Accept` header. He could send `Accept: application/json` for JSON and `Accept: application/xml` for XML. He might even accept multiple types, and it is for the server to decide then what to return.

Unless the server is designed to answer with more than one representation of the resource (JSON or XML, client-selected), there really isn't much choice for the client. But it still is a good thing to have the client send at least "application/json" as his only choice and then return a header `Content-type: application/json` in response. This way, both sides make themselves clear about what they do expect the other side to see the content like.

Now for the versions. If you put the version into the URL, you effectively create different resources (v1 and v2), but in reality you have only one resource (= URL) with different methods to access it. Creating a new version of an API must take place when there is a breaking change in the parameters of a request and/or the representation in the response which is incompatible with the current version.

So when you create an API that uses JSON, you do not deal with generic JSON. You deal with a concrete JSON structure that is somehow unique to your API. You can and probably should indicate this in the `Content-type` sent by the server. The "vendor" extension is there for this: `Content-type: application/vnd.IAMVENDOR.MYAPI+json` will tell the world that the basic data structure is application/json, but it is your company and your API that really tells which structure to expect. And that's exactly where the version for the API request fits in: `application/vnd.IAMVENDOR.MYAPI-v1+json`.

So instead of putting the version in the URL, you expect the client to send an `Accept: application/vnd.IAMVENDOR.MYAPI-v1+json` header, and you respond with `Content-type: application/vnd.IAMVENDOR.MYAPI-v1+json` as well. This really changes nothing for the first version, but let's see how things develop when version 2 comes into play.

The URL approach will create a completely unrelated set of new resources. The client will wonder if `example.com/api/v2/stuff` is the same resource as `example.com/api/v1/stuff`. The client might have created some resources with the v1 API and he stored the URLs for this stuff. How is he supposed to upgrade all these resources to v2? The resources really have not changed, they are the same, the only thing that changed is that they look different in v2.

Yes, the server might notify the client by sending a redirect to the v2 URL. But a redirect does not signal that the client also has to upgrade the client part of the API.

When using an accept header with the version, the URL of the resource is the same for all versions. The client decides to request the resource with either version 1 or 2, and the server might be so kind and still answers version 1 requests with version 1 responses, but all version 2 requests with the new and shiny version 2 responses.

If the server is unable to answer to a version 1 request, he can tell the client by sending HTTP status "406 Not Acceptable" (The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.)

The client can send the accept header with both versions included, which enabled the server to respond with the one he likes most, i.e. a smart client might implement versions 1 and 2 and now sends both as accept header, and waits for the server to upgrade from version 1 to 2. The server will tell in every response whether it is version 1 or 2, and the client can act accordingly - he does not need to know the exact date of the server version upgrade.

To sum it up: For a very basic API with limited, maybe internal, usage even having a version might be overkill. But you never know if this will be true a year from now. It is always a very good idea to include a version number into an API. And the best spot for this is inside the mime type that your API is about to use. Checking for the single existing version should be trivial, but you have the option of transparently upgrading later, without confusing existing clients.

Comment: The restful api is just for my own site's ajax/backbonejs/jquery to use. In this case, should I just stick to the same error code (say 400)? Or return 200 for every AJAX response and check the `success` variable to see if an error has occured

Comment: No, indicating the basic "success/error" fact via an error code is a very good idea. Error responses are handled different by HTTP clients, e.g. they shouldn't be cached etc. Indicating the same inside the data payload is also a good thing. My own API either has "data" on success, or "error" on failure. This is basically the same as having "success = true/false", and it works for me. But do know that status "400 Bad request" is not the generic client error status you think it is. There is no such thing, you have to specify the error status.

Comment: Great answer, Sven!
However, you say: > Regarding versioning: It is considered bad practice to put a version
> tag into the URL I disagree. Here's a [guide](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices/restful-api-design-second-edition) from Apigee who conclude that it *is* indeed the best practice to use version number in the URL. They also clarify the return status codes.

Comment: You are free to disagree. Note that in your video it is said that Apigee follows a pragmatic approach. I wouldn't call that "best" practice. You'll find as many proponents as opponents for this. Proponents usually argue that it is a reasonable easy approach to put the version into the url. Opponents argue that mixing the two things "what you get" and "how it looks" into one thing (URL) is bad.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use 200 status for everything. That just would be confusing.

Jquery allows you to process different response codes differently, there are built in methods for that already so take advantage of using them in your apps and when your app grows you can provide that API for others to use too.

Edit:
Also I highly recommend watching this talk about Laravel and API development:

http://kuzemchak.net/blog/entry/laracon-slides-and-video

Comment: The video link is helpful, but the speaker does some bad things implementing a RESTful API like having the version number in the URL. That's what "Accept" header are for.

Comment: @Sven could you please explain that in more detail on how to use that?  I'm curious =)

Answer (score 1):

There are some list of HTTP Status Code at `Illuminate\Http\Response` that extend to `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`. You can use that in your class.

For example:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response as LaravelResponse;
...
return Response::json('User Exists', LaravelResponse::HTTP_CONFLICT);
```

It much more readable.