# What is the REST equivalent to SOAP's FaultException?

Tags: rest, exception, soap

Since REST doesn't have faults like SOAP does, what would I use in replace of a FaultException?

Comment: This question might be a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600307/best-practice-for-errors-in-restful-api

Answer (score 1):

Since you use SOAP as an example, I'll use SOAP metaphors.

The fault code ("faultcode" in SOAP 1.1, "code" in SOAP 1.2) becomes your HTTP Status-Code. You're constrained a little bit by the HTTP standard for codes here: errors that happened because of something the client did should be in the 4xx range, while completely server-side errors should be in the 5xx range. The generic fallbacks here are 400 and 500, respectively, and you should use the numbers from the HTTP standard when (but *only* when) they make sense for the resource being requested and the error that occurred.

The fault string ("faultstring" in SOAP 1.1, "Reason" in SOAP 1.2) becomes your HTTP Reason-Phrase. This is text.

The details ("detail" in SOAP 1.1, "Detail" in SOAP 1.2) goes in the HTTP entity-body. As long as the format is one that the client will accept (and you return the proper Content-Type header for it), this can be in any format that makes sense for your application.